# static cum instance variable

Tags: java, static, instance-variables

```
public static LoginDetails logindtls = new LoginDetails();
```

I would like to know what happens if an instance variable (like `logindtls` above) is declared as static. Whether it behaves like an instance variable or a static variable; how is memory allocated to it?

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. You clearly see that the variable has the `static` modifier, but you're confused _whether it behaves like a static variable_. How?

Comment: Static cum instance variable? Both are contradictory so it's not possible to do that.

Comment: @PradeepSimha I suppose, you are referring to “static” and “instance”. The purpose of the word “cum” in the phrase is even less clear.

Answer (score 0):

`static` members are handled independently of any created instance or extended class. They don't have access to an instance unless they are given it explicitly.